# Selecting information from a specific range of days and hours using one SQL query

Tags: sql, date, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to filter the date range from April 1 to April 22, but only between 8:00 PM and 6:00 AM - the rest of the hours that are not in this range should be excluded. Do you have any ideas on how to do that? The only thing I have done so far is the date range but I don't know how to handle it next:

```
select * from cdm_service_request_logs
where inserted_at  >= '20/04/01 20:00:00%'
and inserted_at < '20/04/22 06:00:00%'
ORDER BY ID DESC;
```

Comment: (1) Tag with the database you are using.  (2) I don't understand the time filter.  Is that per day or just on the end days?

Comment: (1) I am using Oracle SQL (2) This is a range of days from 1 to 22 April from 20:00 to 06:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
select srl.*
from cdm_service_request_logs srl
where inserted_at >= date '2020-04-01' and
      inserted_at < date '2020-04-022' and
      extract(hour from inserted_at) not between 6 and 19;
```

In Oracle, the time comparison would often use strings:

```
where inserted_at >= date '2020-04-01' and
      inserted_at < date '2020-04-022' and
      (to_char(inserted_at, 'HH24:MI') >= '20:00' or
       to_char(inserted_at, 'HH24:MI') < '06:00'
      )
```

Note that the date comparison uses date constant values.  This is correct.  The `%` is not valid for a date, so your comparisons are as strings.  I can only speculate that you are confusing `like` patterns with date constants.  If so, that is just misguided.